# Recolor text based on "check box" select number and sequence in HTML+ JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

This is a kind of odd question I guess but I dont find a way to solve it either.

I have 10 check boxes to select in right side and a sentence in the left side in a HTML page. What I need is, the sentence should remain red in color until I check first 4 check boxes.

If I further check  the 5th~7th [that is 1st to 7th] check box the left side sentence should be yellow color promptly.

And if I check the whole check boxes, the left side should be green in color.

```
----------------------------------------

                                   |   check box 1
                                   |   check box 2
                                   |   check box 3
                                   |   check box 4
Sentence to be colored             |   check box 5
                                   |   check box 6
                                   |   check box 7
                                   |   check box 8
                                   |   check box 9
                                   |   check box 10
                                   |
```

---

I believe I should use JavaScript for this but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: What if check box 1, 2, 3 and 5 are clicked? What should be the color?

Comment: @Harry: I should mentioned this before, sorry. If 1,2,3 and 5 are checked the color should be another [for example blue]. So the logic is, if the check boxes are not selected sequentially with desired numbers the text color should be BLUE. More simply, anything except the logic [posted in the original question's description] should return BLUE. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery you could do something along the lines of

```
if($("#Checkbox1").is(":checked") && $("#Checkbox2").is(":checked")) //etc do this for each checkbox up to 7
{
    $("#Sentence").css("color", "yellow");
}
```

Hope this helps get you started.

Comment: @Bennm: That was cool. I am such a dump who couldn't have this idea either. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @MohammadKhalidMasud THankyou. Please feel free to upvote and if appropriate mark as an accepted answer.